# Is there a way to inject to a constant in angular? If not, how could I rewrite this?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

So we have this:

```
user.settings.data =  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: 'megacow'
};

angular.module('user').constant('userSettings.data', user.settings.data);
```

--which is used in various other places.

However, it's been proposed to inject one of our services to this in order to make the object run-time configurable. Is there a way to do that here? If not, how is this best re-written?

Basically want something that works like this, hypothetically (I know this is invalid code.)

```
user.settings.data =  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 2,
    prop3: i18n('megacow')
};

angular.module('user').constant('userSettings.data', 'i18n', user.settings.data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a service out of it and expose the data, something like this:

```
angular.module('user').factory('UserSettingsService', ['i18n', function(i18n) {

  var _value3 = 'megacow';

  var data = {
        value: '', // Some constant
        value2: '', // Another constant
        value3Raw: _value3, // "Variable"
        value3Converted: i18n(_value3 ) // Calculated value
  }

  function setValue3(newValue) {
       _value3 = newValue
  }

    return {
        data: data,
        setValue3: setValue3
    };
}]);
```

That way you can inject the `UserSettingsService` and use it to store constants, variables and calculated values.

PS: I haven´t tested the code myself, so forgive-me if there are any syntax mistakes.

Comment: I will not forgive you

Comment: :D was that helpful at least?

Comment: Yes. We ended up finding an alternative but this does work. Thanks.